# Code works in Python shell but not with command prompt

Tags: python, linux, shell, operating-system, cmd

I'm new to python and this is my first real program.
Heres the code:

```
def home():
    print ('game....play-1..options-2..rules-3..exit-4..')
    answer = input()
    print(repr(answer))
    if answer == '1':
        play()
    elif answer == '2':
        options()
    elif answer == '3':
        rules()
    elif answer == '4':
        end()


def rules():
    print ('rules...main menu-1...exit-2..')
    answerRules = input ()
    print(repr(answerRules))    
    if answerRules == '1':
        home()
    elif answerRules == '2':
        end()

home()
```

The main problem i get here is that it works fine in the python shell but not with command prompt. In command prompt `home()` works however once you enter an answer, e.g. 3. the program just ends.

Comment: What version of python? If 2.x, input will return an int, not a string

Comment: I think that you should mention the operating system you use.

Comment: Works on my system. Win7_64 + python 3.0.1 (2 bit).
Please mention your OS & python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is type of `int`

so check with `if answer == 1:`
It will resolve

Comment: I think the `print()` function suggests that the OP is on `python3.x`, so `input()` is not an int in that case.

Comment: @OliverBennett you're on python 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if input() is returning the carriage return or some other character when you run it from the command prompt.